# Changing the background color of body of HTML by clicking anywhere in the body of document using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image]

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
         
         
         let mybody=document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
         function f(){
         //mybody.style.background-color="red";
         mybody.style.backgroundColor = "red";
         }
         
         mybody.onclick=f();
        
         
        
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>

    lorem ipsum
     
    </body>


</html>
```

I want to change the background  color when the body section is clicked.I am getting error,"Cannot read property 'style' of undefined".
Why is my mybody undefined in this case?

```
mybody.style.background-color="red";
mybody.style.backgroundColor = "red";
```

In both above cases,it says mybody is undefined

Answer (score 3):

```js
function setBackground() {
     let mybody=document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
     //mybody.style.background-color="red";
     mybody.style.backgroundColor = "red";
     
}
```

```html
<body onclick="setBackground()"  style="width: 5000px; height: 5000px;">
</body>
```

Because `body` does not exist yet at the point when you intend to execute it. Remember, the `script` is in `head`, `body` is ***below*** it. An easy solution would be:

```
function setBackground() {
     let mybody=document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
     //mybody.style.background-color="red";
     mybody.style.backgroundColor = "red";
     
}
```

and define `onclick="setBackground()"` in `body`.

Comment: You could also move the script to the end of the body, which is a more useful place for a lot of scripts to be. Or use the `<script defer>` attribute.

Comment: with this it sets the color to red when page is loaded,not when we click the body section(that was the requirement) ,

Comment: @user20913 it is an onclick event, which is triggered on click. You probably have some code remaining in your work that causes trouble.

Comment: @user20913 created a snippet for you, please try it out, it's in my answer.

Comment: @LajosArpad
onclick="setBackground()" On clicking what function will be called?

Comment: @user20913 `onclick` is an attribute of `body` which defines what Javascript code is to be executed upon clicking on the element. In our case it is `setBackround()`, which means that the function which is being called is `setBackround`.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried with `document.querySelctor("body")`

Comment: It's `querySelector`, not `querySelctor` and in this case that's not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I will do something like this :

```
document.body.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    document.body.style.backgroundColor="red"
});
```

But your code should also work with this

```
   var mybody = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];// or with just document.querySelector('body');
   
   function f(){document.body.backgroundColor = 'red'; }
   mybody.onClick = f;
```

Comment: `body` simply does not exist at that point, see my answer.